# How to create an Aurelia-Validation Validation object for Jasmine tests

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, aurelia

I'm currently using the Aurelia-Validation plugin to do client side validation. Since the validation object must be injected into the calling class's constructor, all my jasmine tests for the class in question now fail(since there's no validation object being passed in)

I've been trying to create a mock Validation object for a while now, or even a real one but i can't seem to get it right. The closest I've gotten is:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    cache = new Cache();
    session = new Session();
    var valCon = new ValidationConfig();
    var obsLoc = new ObserverLocator();
    sut = new InsuredInformation(session, cache, new Validation(obsLoc,valCon));
});
```

But I keep getting errors when I run Karma saying:

```
TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got [object Object]
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the validation object and how i have instantiated it. Has anyone successfully created Jasmine tests for Aurelia View-Models that make use of the aurelia-validation plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `Container` to instantiate your object. You may need to initialize the platform abstraction layer.

```js
import {Container} from 'aurelia-framework'; // or 'aurelia-dependency-injection'
import {initialize as initializePAL} from 'aurelia-pal-browser'; // you may need to `jspm install aurelia-pal-browser`
initializePAL();

beforeEach(() => {
  let container = new Container();
  sut = container.get(InsuredInformation);
  foo = container.get(SomeOtherClassThatYouWantToTest);
});
```

Comment: Tried this out, i get errors with TaskQueue -> Object[object Object] has no method 'createMutationObserver' which im guessing goes back to the Validation object

Comment: Still nothing, Now i get undefined is not a function. I think the validation object is still being instantiated incorrectly and that might be messing up the instantiation of my sut?

Comment: ok bummer- let me see if I can find a `aurelia-validation` expert to answer

Comment: Yeah, it's becoming a proper mystery, I'm writing jasmine tests but i can't actually run them for my class